# save many to many relation in Laravel elequent 5?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have three table,`employees`,`allowances` and `emp_allowances`

In `employees`

- id
- name

In `allowances`

- id
- title
- amount

In `emp_allowances`

- employees_id
- allowances_id
- amount

Model functions are, `Employee`

```
  public function empAllowances() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\EmplAllowance', 'emp_allowances', 'employees_id', 'allowances_id');
}
```

`Allowance`

```
 public function employees() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Employee');
}
```

It is working here `$emp->empAllowances()->sync([1]);` but when I am following this method,I can not save `amount`.

How can I save employee allowance details with `amount`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$emp->empAllowances()->sync([1 => ['amount' => 10]])
```

Search for `Adding Pivot Data When Syncing`  [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)

Comment: What if we have multiple ids to sync with model?